# TinyMCE / Tinybrowser upload tab giving a 404

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

Just looking for a bit of help with Tinybrowser - I've tried updating it to the latest version but it's still failing. If I click the 'Upload' tab I get a 404.. I'm thinking it's possibly to do with the htaccess, but I'm not too hot with htaccess rules so I can't pinpoint it.

If I visit the page directly (/admin/javascript/tiny_mce/plugins/tinybrowser/upload.php?type=image&tokenget=315af6ee7cf85bc6170760a0c1a5b86d&folder=) I get a 404 as well. If I take off 'folder=' it'll go to the page, if I make it follllder=, it'll go to the page. So for some reason 'folder=' seems to be causing problems. Even if I manually put in a string for the folder var.

The htaccess is as follows:

```
# default
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Make sure there's no way of getting to this file
<FilesMatch "\.htaccess$">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteRule ^login(/*)$ system/login/ [L,QSA]

# Route all other traffic to index.php (front controller)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_args=$1 [L,QSA]
AddType text/x-component htc
```

If I remove

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_args=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I end up getting a 403 forbidden error, but obviously it's not really feasible to remove this line anyway.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Check your httpd logs. Without understanding exactly what the final request looks like, its hard to guess what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well.

The problem appears to be a security restriction on some servers that relates to the filename of the PHP file, as well as the "folder=" querystring.

I got around it by renaming upload.php to upload_tab.php, and then modifying tinybrowser.php to reference the upload_tab.php file:

```
if($tinybrowser['allowupload']) 
    {
    ?><li id="upload_tab"><span><a href="upload_tab.php?type=<?php echo $typenow.$passfolder.$passfeid; ?>"><?php echo TB_UPLOAD; ?></a></span></li><?php
    }
```

This allows you to see the upload window, and submit some files using POST variables.

However, a problem remains...

The particular server I came across also has a similar restriction on a request to upload_file.php with a querystring of 'folder='.  There isn't an easy fix for this, apart from decompiling flexupload.swf (which I tried, but couldn't recompile it) so I couldn't fully resolve the issue.